# Are there enough Spartan Points to unlock everything?

Tags: halo-4

In Halo 4, when you rank up, you receive a certain amount of Spartan Points. (I believe it's one per level, but I don't know that for sure) This "currency" is then used to buy weapons, armor abilities, grenades, etc. for use in customized loadouts.

My question is are there enough Spartan Points gained by getting to level 50 to unlock everything? Or will it eventually come down to my preference as to what weapons/upgrades to unlock and use?

Comment: I have to imagine they give you enough points to unlock all of the various upgrades.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [this post at Se7enSins](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/halo-4-rank-explanation-max-rank-explanation.810345/) and my personal experience, I think my initial calculation was slightly off.

First, the question is how many SP will you get at maximum.  By my calculations the answer is **51** (leveling to 50), including 1 SP for level 1 and 1 SP for completing level 50.

[Based on the IGN wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Loadouts), it would cost **51 SP** (noting an error on their part, as the AR costs 0 SP, not 1) to cover all of the "Loadout" upgrades.  ***So at exactly level 50, you will have enough SP.***

Nothing costs SP besides the loadout unlocks.  I have now leveled past 50 and can confirm that you can unlock everything that costs SP once you hit 50, and you do not get SP for Specializations (because you've already unlocked everything).

### So, at level 50, you have enough SP to unlock everything.

Comment: The armor unlocks (at least thus far) don't cost SP to unlock.  When you hit the Spartan Rank (or complete the commendation required) you unlock them for free.

Comment: I didn't realize that leveling the specializations would award SP. It will take until a couple levels into my first spec until I can unlock everything, but I think I can probably live without some of the less useful loadout upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: good edit and great answer, would +1 again if I could.

Answer (score 0):

**CHART OF HALO - RANKS - SP - EXP**

Said to be reliable. I believe them.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a little more detail on what it is you linked?

Comment: You can link inline images like this.

Answer (score -1):

There actaully are three extra ones upon reaching rank 130 with unlocking all loadout options

Comment: Would you care to expand on your answer? Are you saying you get 3x more Spartan Points when you reach SR130?